# How to apply css styles to TextCell and change TextColor

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms-styles

I want to change the *TextColor* of a *TextCell* in a *ListView* with CSS styles.

I tried the following, but the color remains unchanged:

```
MenuPage TextCell {
    color: aqua;
    textcolor: aqua;
    text-color: aqua;
    TextColor: aqua;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had no luck with TextCell.  But if you can make it a Label in a ViewCell:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="{Binding}" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

then you can style it with CSS:

```
ListView StackLayout Label {
    font-size: 14;
    color: black;
}
```